# Codeception: how to test if an image is loaded?

Tags: selenium, codeception, facebook-php-webdriver

I'm trying to do this

```
$I->seeElement('DIV#security IMG.verisign');
```

to check *if the images with the Verisign logo is loaded*, but the test *passes* even if the image is not loaded (for a 404 if the file name of the source is wrong).

**What's the right way to check for image loaded?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [naturalHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) to validate that the image correctly loaded:

```
$this->assertGreaterThan($element->getAttribute('naturalHeight'), 1);
```